# Bash Script interactive mv issues

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script to help organize files and I want to use mv -i to make sure I don't write over something important.

The script is working right now except for the -i for the mv.

It shows (y/n [n]) not overwritten part, but then goes and and doesn't allow me to interact with it.

```
createList()
{
    ls *.epub | sed 's/-.*//' |uniq >> list.txt
    ls *.mobi | sed 's/-.*//' |uniq >> list2.txt
}

atag()
{
    find /Users/j/Desktop/Source -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.epub" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' tag -a Purple {}
    find /Users/j/Desktop/Source -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.mobi" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' tag -a Purple {}
}

moveEpub()
{
    while read -r line; do
        if [ -d "/Users/j/Desktop/Dest/$line" ]; then
            if [ -d "/Users/j/Desktop/Dest/$line/EPUB" ]; then
                find /Users/j/Desktop/Source/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$line*" -and ! -iname ".*$line*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv -i {} /Users/j/Desktop/Dest/"$line"/EPUB/
            else
                mkdir "/Users/j/Desktop/Dest/$line/EPUB"
                find /Users/j/Desktop/Source/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$line*" -and ! -iname ".*$line*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv -i {} /Users/j/Desktop/Dest/"$line"/EPUB/
            fi
        fi
    done < "list.txt"
}

moveMobi()
{
    while read -r line; do
        if [ -d "/Users/j/Desktop/Dest/$line" ]; then
            if [ -d "/Users/j/Desktop/Dest/$line/MOBI" ]; then
                find /Users/j/Desktop/Source/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$line*" -and ! -iname ".*$line*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv -i {} /Users/j/Desktop/Dest/"$line"/MOBI/
            else
                mkdir "/Users/j/Desktop/Dest/$line/MOBI"
                find /Users/j/Desktop/Source/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$line*" -and ! -iname ".*$line*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv --interactive {} /Users/j/Desktop/Dest/"$line"/MOBI/
            fi
        fi
    done < "list2.txt"
}

clear
createList
atag
moveEpub
moveMobi
rm list.txt
rm list2.txt
```

Comment: BTW, using `ls` in scripts is a serious code smell. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: `epubs=( *.epub ); printf '%s\n' "${epubs[@]%%-*}" | uniq >>list.txt` might be one slightly-better way to do it. (Still not quite right, on account of reliance on `uniq` and thus representation of files in a NUL-delimited stream).

Comment: ...of course, you could also just keep track of which names you were done with rather than trying to `uniq` it at all, which would allow your lists to be NUL-delimited (thus created with `printf '%s\0'` and read with `IFS= read -r -d ''`, and completely impervious to unexpected content in filenames). `declare -A completed=( ); while read -r line; do [[ ${completed[$line]} ]] && continue; completed[$line]=1; ...; done`

Comment: That said -- why are you putting `list` and `list2` in files at all rather than just iterating directly over glob contents?

Comment: BTW, as for why you can't interact with `mv`, it's because your stdin has been redirected from the files reading `list.txt` and `list2.txt`; I'll answer to that effect (and with a workaround) shortly.

Comment: ...I'm not really clear on why you're using `find` rather than globs to iterate over in the `atag` function either.

Comment: I didn't know about globs or the find --exec commands.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `mv -i` to interact with the terminal, that means its stdin needs to be attached to that terminal. There are several places, here, where you're overriding stdin.

---

For instance:

```
# THIS LOOP OVERRIDES STDIN
while read -r line
  ...
done <list.txt
```

...redirects stdin for the entire duration of the loop, so instead of reading from the user, `mv` reads from `list.txt`. To change this, use a different file descriptor:

```
# This loop uses FD 3 for stdin
while read -r line <&3
  ...
done 3<list.txt
```

---

Another place is in calling `xargs`. Instead of:

```
# Overrides stdin for xargs and mv to contain output from find
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv -i '{}' "$dest"
```

...use:

```
# directly executes mv from find, stdin not modified
find ... -exec mv -i '{}' "$dest" ';'
```

---

That said, I would suggest ditching `list.txt` and `list2.txt` altogether; you simply don't need them; for that matter, you don't need `find` either.

```
dest=/Users/j/Desktop/Dest
source=/Users/j/Desktop/Source
moveEpub() {
  local -A finished=( )                    # WARNING: This requires bash 4.0 or newer.
  for name in *.epub; do
    prefix=${name%%-*}                     # remove everything past the first dash
    [[ ${finished[$prefix]} ]] && continue # skip if already done with this prefix
    finished[$prefix]=1                    # set flag to skip other files w/ this prefix
    [[ -d $dest/$prefix ]] || continue     # skip if no directory exists for this prefix
    mkdir -p "$dest/$prefix/EPUB"          # create destination if not existing
    mv -i "$source"/*"$prefix"* "$dest/$prefix/EPUB"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in `find` action `-exec` instead of piping to `xargs` :

```
find /Users/j/Desktop/Source/ -maxdepth 1 \
    -iname "*$line*" -and ! -iname ".*$line*" -type f \
    -exec mv -i {} /Users/j/Desktop/Dest/"$line"/EPUB/ \;
```

Comment: Good catch, but stdin is also redirected at the scope of the surrounding `while read` loop(s).